# tabs don't work when I am losing focus

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I have a GUI consists of 3 tab control
when I click on each tab the controls on that tab appears (there is a dialog for each tab that I show when that tab clicked)
the application has another dialog, when I change the focus on that dialog or any other window or program and return back to the main program I just can see the tab I left before and when I click the other tabs they don't show up.

I initialize tabs in `WM_INITDIALOG` and I show when each one is clicked in `WM_NOTIFY` like this:

```
 case WM_NOTIFY:

    switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
    {
        case TCN_SELCHANGING:
        {
            // Return FALSE to allow the selection to change.
            return FALSE;
        }
        break;

        case TCN_SELCHANGE:
        {

            if( TabCtrl_GetCurSel( ( ( LPNMHDR ) lParam) -> hwndFrom ) == 0 ) {

                ShowWindow( hwndTimeFrame, SW_HIDE );
                ShowWindow( hwndAR, SW_HIDE );
                ShowWindow( hwndInsFeed, SW_SHOW );

            } 
            if( TabCtrl_GetCurSel( ( ( LPNMHDR ) lParam) -> hwndFrom ) == 1 ) 
                {

                    ShowWindow( hwndInsFeed, SW_HIDE );
                    ShowWindow( hwndAR, SW_HIDE );
                    ShowWindow( hwndTimeFrame, SW_SHOW );

                }
            if( TabCtrl_GetCurSel( ( ( LPNMHDR ) lParam) -> hwndFrom ) == 2 )
                {

                    ShowWindow( hwndInsFeed, SW_HIDE );
                    ShowWindow( hwndTimeFrame, SW_HIDE );
                    ShowWindow( hwndAR, SW_SHOW );
                }



        }

        break;
    }
    break;
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you verify that you are still receiving `TCN_SELCHANGE` notifications and that `TabCtrl_GetCurSel()` is not failing?

Comment: yes  do. I trace the program and each time I go through each 'IF' correctly but "ShowWindow"s has no effect !

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out this. 
I initialized the tab in `WM_INITDIALOG` which turned out to be the problem, because each time the application showing the tab dialogs it send this message and initialize them again. I remove this part from initdialog to initialization of the application before entering the message loop